# Unable to decrypt message from gnupg and PHP

Tags: php, encryption, gnupg

I don't have any problem with `Encryption` but I'm unable to `Decrypt` the text.

The response which I receive is simply `false`. The code looks like this

```
            putenv("GNUPGHOME=/tmp");
            $gpg = new \gnupg();
            $key = $gpg->import($user->pgp_key);
            $gpg->addencryptkey($key['fingerprint']);
            $encrypted_text = "
            -----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----

            hQEMA8b5QPvIxFcnAQgAl55QDu/QPn5A16Ag0+GAGwWzFVJcj4zGQMTVMHRNoZJw
            h29gWkIjXXtgyBxsQCv+tiLxuyBmtUR1r45RDyZgtunrATtJAMBHOEORDZ8bRQps
            87mY5Tw3VklLokAahjnJiqzY/HrodjQLXMdk8FXXoNk+SvZq+gdr5XVqAEtKgn/8
            24NMzWD+k+zZL+8GLi3Fb2C6C2/go4oJBW+pTzNZF1yIkaIqpJp/T2nvp879bi1s
            t8sUbGEUyVcJ8/qdQs1D4tq3g327RypHV9KV0nJ8fCCjN186uKrn4EUNaOB9p3RQ
            IbeP94V5jGDNJdfdUOcfuiHS74cRLgNsSGf2S80ipNKSATApW498uYae7EtSHK/N
            tEli+Mg3ZgJZ6iSoBEPsCSSSQmBprmha8W9SoXRT1LhvMXZZLdGGOCMOSgbS5cx1
            Sl23jUK7xANGKwwyw4tSNh0G6yjULJ/bU00jMyhX/JyOQ64ZeKQdyW+z7pFs5n7u
            SC7Y3V/kNjjyHzJshV4P9nru56sfyghA90GZoA3+R6LOvWE=
            =gKpy
            -----END PGP MESSAGE-----";


            $plain = $gpg->decrypt($encrypted_text);
```

`var_dump($plain);` return `bool(false)`

I'm using `gnupg` version and `PHP` version

```
GPGme Version   1.7.1
Extension Version   1.4.0
PHP 7.0.18
```

Any idea why decryption fail?

Comment: You have to supply a key to decrypt it also. I don't see that happening in your code.

Comment: Okay, that's make sense. But where should I add it? I can't see it in php manuals

Comment: Check the documenation. Try this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-decrypt.php

Comment: Try with: `$gpg->adddecryptkey($key['fingerprint']);`. (You're using `addencryptkey()` but you need to set the `adddecryptkey()`, which is a different method)

Comment: Oh, I've added `addencryptkey` instead of `adddecryptkey`. Anyway when I try `$gpg->adddecryptkey($key['fingerprint'], 'MYPASSHERE');` I still got `bool(false)`

Comment: Use the [`geterror` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gnupg-geterror.php) to receive further details on why the decryption call failed.

Comment: Sorry for the delay but I was offline for past 10 days. The error is `Exception get_key failed`

Comment: @Ivan Same here..